# PHP, how include variables from another file identified a URL variable

Tags: php

I'm looking to do something really rather simple but I'm quite new to PHP so please pardon my naivety.

My requirement is to have a simple page (here on referenced as **base**) which will be populated by values from another file (here on referenced as **inc**). The output HTML from **base** may look something like this:

```
    <h2>Name: [dynamic string (e.g. Joe Bloggs) ]</h2>
    <h2>Age: [dynamic value (e.g. 31) ]</h2>
    <h2>Bio: [dynamic string (e.g. I was born and raised in the UK. My special features are rocket boots.)</h2>
```

I plan on using a URL parameter (e.g. "www.mydomain.com/base.php?id=1234") to identify the name of the **inc** file that will be used in a `get` request.

I'm not exactly sure if this is the best way to go about it, but as this is a REALLY simple project I want to avoid using mySQL or anything else to complicate matters in production.

Please can you advise:

1. How should I construct the **inc** PHP file? Would it be best to create the variables in this as a form or array?
2. How can I configure the **base** PHP to pull in the variables that are set in an external file

Please let me know if my logic is way off & this is completely the wrong way to go about it!

As I mentioned before, this is a very simple project so I would like to stick to raw PHP (no 3rd party tools) as I'm using this to educate myself. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

absolute simplest method:

include_data.php:

```
<?php

$name = 'Joe Bloggs';
$age = 31;
$bio = 'I was born and raised ...';
```

biopage.php:

```
<?php

include('include_data.php');

?>

<h2>Name: <?php echo $name ?></h2>
<h2>Age: <?php echo $age ?></h2>
<h2>Bio: <?php echo $bio ?></h2>
```

That's all you **REALLY** need to make a "dynamic" page in php. Everything else is just fancier and fancier versions of this.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for the suggestion! So that I can make this dynamic, would I be correct in thinking I could change "include_data" to be a variable to be set from the URL?

Comment: you can, but if you directly allow specifying files to include via url, you open your system to HUGE security vulnerabilities. unless you do it right, a malicious user can get your server to spit out ANY file on your server: e.g. `http://example.com/bio.php?inc=../../../../../../../etc/passwd`

Comment: If I was to just reference the id in the URL (eg `www.mydomain.com/file.php?id=1234`). and create a location in my PHP file would this alleviate the issue?

Answer (score 1):

if your inc files look like:

```
<?php
$name = "My Name";
$age = 21;
$bio = "This is my bio";
```

base.php would look something like this:

```
<?php
$inc = $_GET['id'] . ".inc.php";
include($inc); // or require($inc); if you want to throw an error if $inc doesn't exist
?>
<h2>Name: <?=$name?></h2>
<h2>Age: <?=$age?></h2>
<h2>Bio: <?=$bio?></h2>
```

you'd want to append whatever subdirectory your inc file's in if it's not in the same directory as base.php.  Also you could check if $inc file actually exists and display an error if necessary.

you could have the variables in the inc files in an array, I don't think it makes much of a difference in such a simple example.